# How to bind NSTableView to a custom collection class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I know how to bind a `NSTableView` to an `NSArray` via `NSArrayController`.

But what about binding `NSTableView` to `MyCustomCollection`? What do the bindings look like? Can I still use `NSArrayController` and just conform to a protocol in `MyCustomCollection`? Or should I use a different controller object? What does `MyCustomCollection` need to conform to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to answer completely or specifically without knowing a lot more about your collection class. Almost certainly creating a custom collection class is the wrong thing to do. You should definitely elaborate on the reasons you feel this is necessary and your implementation. Be prepared to consider your reasons aren't good enough to justify jamming a custom collection into an `NSArrayController` or that it's not even possible to do exactly what you want (at least the way you're trying to do it).

Also note Cocoa collection classes are (I think all) members of a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ClassCluster.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH7-SW1). This makes "doing it right" a significantly more complex challenge and makes subclassing an existing Cocoa collection class a Bad Idea™ if you have to ask how ("if you have to ask, you're not ready to try it" conceit, albeit justified).

I believe as long as your class responds to the same selectors as does (at least) `NSArray` (if not `NSMutableArray` if your class is mutable), including the [Key Value Coding collection accessor methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html), it should probably work alright. Since your table (or, more likely, its columns) is bound to the array controller, that part should work the same. Since `NSArrayController` inherits `-content` / `-setContent:` from `NSObjectController` and these methods take an `id` argument, I believe it likely uses the KVC accessor methods I referenced to get at the collection's members.

But I could be wrong... :-)

Comment: This has been my suspicion so far: that it's best to just use the available tools rather than creating custom methods. My first question when learning about `NSArrayController` is: "What if my data is not so neatly stored in memory?". For example a chat application using `NSTableView` to display chat history, where chat history is a union of some things in memory and, if we reach back far enough, stuff from a .txt file.

Comment: Your case can still easily be represented in memory using existing Cocoa classes (including collection classes) in a very ordinary object graph. If a "message" class has a "text" string attribute, a "date" attribute, a "from" string (or reference to a "user" class with its own "name" string, etc.), then you simply stuff each "message" into an array or mutable array and your Cocoa controls are then bound to the controller's arrangedObjects.text or arrangedObjects.user.name key paths to get at the data. That simple. Not convinced your case needs a custom collection by this description.

Comment: Ran out of room, but definitely study KVC/KVO thoroughly if you haven't already. I suspect you just haven't yet grasped how to walk an object graph through an array controller's collection and are "chasing an untamed ornithoid without cause" to quote Commander Data. ;-)

Comment: The best thing I've found so far is to simply use `NSArrayController` with a subclass of `NSMutableArray` where I use my own "virtual" backing store. Using existing methods, and conforming to the subclass recommendations from the docs, would you say this is probably the best way?

Comment: Don't subclass collection classes unless you know enough about their internals (are an Apple engineer) to not have to ask in the first place. Seriously. This is *WAY* overcomplicating things. Read in and assemble your data using Cocoa classes specific to your schema and put them into a standard collection class. Using a collection class to do the job of an object graph is ... not a sane way to do things.

Comment: (You should need, at most, a data model consisting of three classes: Conversation <--->> Message <<---> User  ...  "User" and "Conversation" may be optional in your case, but you get the idea. "Message" is the meat: its attributes are merely an NSString, an NSDate, and maybe references to a conversation and a "from" user. It's none of a collection class's business how its members relate with other objects and it *never should be*. What you're proposing is making data structure *entirely* the collection's job. Don't do that. :-))

Comment: To elaborate on "don't subclass Cocoa collection classes", it's because of their being members of a class cluster. Imagine an internal Cocoa framework operation needing to copy or "magic" your collection in one of the many other ways it does. Since, as a cluster, even a -copy operation could return a completely different class of object (because it's none of your business anyway, by design), your custom collection class could suddenly (and probably catastrophically) become a plain old NSArray when used internally by some part of the Cocoa machinery. Good luck debugging *that*.

Comment: Good points... I just find it hard to believe there's no good way to represent "virtual" data. For example a web service which can serve up potentially millions of items. For today, I'll stick to keeping everything in memory. As for reading in all the chat history, I'll just read it into memory as needed similar to web page infinite scrolling.

Comment: If a web service returns millions of items all in one response, that web service is Doing It Wrong. Results should be sent in batches from some offset ("give me the nth page of search results, 10 at a time", etc.). The consumer can ask for a result count and then ask for only the results it needs to display/scroll relatively smoothly.

Comment: That's what I meant... how would I bind to such a data source? That is not a NSArray you're describing...

Comment: In the background, you gather the results and translate from the service (probably JSON objects?) to your own object graph, creating instances for whatever you need and adding them to the array controller's content.